# Access mysql database to create pentaho dashbord using CTools

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-ctools

I'm using CTools under Pentaho BI Server; I want to generate reports with an external MySQL database.

I correctly added the data source, and the test of connectivity return OK
but i don't know how i can access this database when creating a CDE.

@+,

Answer (score 0):

when you click on new CDE report you will find one link on above right corner as a datasourse penel,

-> Click on datasource penal

-> their on left side you will find tab of Sql Queries from that 
->select option SQL over sqljndi , properties tab  will open, their select the database you want to access in jndi column.